# Invisible link on Low Quality Review Queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review-queue

While taking a look at an item in the Low Quality Posts queue, I noticed an oddity.  There's an invisible link to delete the post:

[image: Cropped image showing the highlighted invisible link]

When I mouseover the link, it changes color, which is how I noticed it.  Inspecting the page, I see that this link is in a div.post-menu element on the page, which probably should be removed, or set to display:none;

Comment: Weird, that artifact is present even to users who cannot even vote to delete (I see it on [security.se] as well, and I don't have 10k there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks for the report.